# C# ASP.net WebForms postback without update/refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, postback

I have an ASP.net WebForms website.
In one of the pages, I want to send a message to the server so the server keeps up to date with the changes on the client.
In simple terms, a postback from a textbox or button or w/e will do except that it also refreshes the page.

I want to just do a web request to the server, but keeping the same session so I still have the session variables on the server side.

Again, I am not looking for the UpdatePanel feature which is what most questions similar to this propose.

Comment: Why would you lose session state after a postback?

Comment: I wouldn't, but a postback would refresh the page, which is not what I want. Also, the session part is for the server side so it also has access to all session variables. This is the reason why I cannot just do a simple web requests (rest-like).

Comment: Maybe just use jquery ajax and a webmethod then - https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx

Comment: I will take a look into it

Comment: Using the web methods worked as I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to send information to your server without a postback (or using an UpdatePanel), you can use an AJAX asynchronous call.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CS.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
</script>
```

where in this example the aspx page URL is CS.aspx and the method name is GetCurrentTime. Data can be sent as JSON which will need to be parsed on the server method.